# how to set password as pixels of image in android(cued click point or grapical password)

Tags: android, database, graphics, passwords

am creating an lo-gin application where am going to make the password as pixels of images.let me more specific i have 3 category animals,car,baby's each category contain the there images.now the user can select pictures  from this category and select any portion of the image and can set the password (example in animals i select the eye of a lion as the first password) like that i can select as many passwords as i can .now how can i implement this method can any one give me some ideas or any source code so that i can implement this idea

Comment: i have finally found a solution and i have made a graphical password app .thank you for all for the responses

Comment: If you found would you Please share this technique ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take in user input for touchPrecision when the portion has been touched - either Coarse or Fine or Super-fine - this is a user setting

Store the following when registering the password

- touch1 of image1 of Category1 happened at x11, y11
- touch1 of image2 of Category2 happened at x21, y21
- touch1 of image1 of Category3 happened at x31, y31
- touchPrecision is Fine

(This assumes user chose three images - one from each category and clicked on a portion of the image in each category)

Now at the time of login - 
 for each touch make sure the correct category and image was chosen - when user touches a portion of the image, make sure the user touche is *close enough* to the portion stored earlier. The tolerance for *close enough* depends upon the touchPrecision. For example assume Coarse is set 60, Fine is set to 30 and super-fine set to 10. If touchPrecision is Fine then the user input touch location at the time of login must be within circle of 30% radius from the center of this circle- say which was at x11 y11

my estimate - 10 - 16 hours for an alpha version that implements this algorithm on Android.

You can make it more sophisticated by grabbing a histogram ....